Fluid Simulation is not working as I intended
I have been getting into fluid simulations. In the scene I have the monkey model, bucket (which rotates to expel the fluid), the ground (plane) along with the emitting sphere and domain cube.
I tried to make the domain larger because the particles began to fill in a box in the middle of the scene which I didn’t want. Now when I bake the animation, nothing appears. How can I fix this?
Also to note, I am using Blender 4.1 on MacOS.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BTIdMhZ1Q3Gn1GU_meYWzPjhTpA8oOdS/view?usp=sharing

I think your Inflow object is too small compared to the size of the domain and the resolution (56). Also, your domain object is quite big which means you have to turn up the resolution and spend more time on computation. Does it help ? I'm not getting a single fluid particle with your file, without increasing the resolution.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

@Lutzi Thank you for reviewing the file. I’ll have a further look at the project tomorrow and will get back to you once I tinker the settings using your advice
